# ELISA in R: how to use curve-specific estimates when applying the ED function to a drc obejct?

Tags: r, response, predict, curve, drc

Assume that we would like to estimate the concentrations of 2000 samples (500 individuals with 4 samples each) from their observed absorptions. The relationship between absorption and concentration is derived by observing the absorptions of some controls with known concentrations. This procedure is repeated for a variety of plates each with different samples and controls. The plate identifier is stored in the variable `CURVE`.

The first step of the estimation in R can be handled using the argument `curveid` in the `drm` function (`drc` package). The code below fits plate-specific 4-parameter logistics models for the relationship between the control absorptions, `ctrlA`, and the logarithm of the control concentrations, `logctrlC`:

```
model1 <- drm(ctrlA~logctrlC, curveid = CURVE, fct=LL.4(names=c("Slope", "Lower", "Upper", "ED50")), logDose=exp(1), data = controls)
```

The next step involves the very estimation of the sample concentrations, `C`, using the model object fitted with `drm` above and the absorption values of the samples which are stored in the variable `A`. This should be possible using the function `ED`:

```
C <- ED(model1, respLev = A, type="absolute", logBase=exp(1))
```

Each observation of `A` is of course connected to a value of `CURVE` which was initially supplied in the `curveid` argument of the `drm` function.

**Question:** how is it possible to use the curve/plate-specific estimates e.g. using the `ED` function? This function has an argument called `pool` which in the documentation is described as:

```
pool    
logical. If TRUE curves are pooled. Otherwise they are not. This argument only works for models with independently fitted curves as specified in drm.
```

I may have missed something, but I am not able to see how to take advantage of the `curveid` when calculating the final estimates.

**Edit:** Below is some generated example data (code and output) which may illustrate the task

```
    set.seed(5)
    
    CURVE <- sort(rep(seq(1,25,1),4))
    ctrl_n <- rep(seq(1,4,1),25)
    ctrlC <- rep(c(1,10,40,250),25)
    logctrlC <- log(ctrlC)
    ctrlA <- rep(NA,100)
    controls <- data.frame(CURVE, ctrl_n, ctrlA, ctrlC, logctrlC)
    controls$ctrlA[controls$ctrl_n==1] <- abs(rnorm(25, 0.05, 0.01))
    controls$ctrlA[controls$ctrl_n==2] <- abs(rnorm(25, 0.60, 0.25))
    controls$ctrlA[controls$ctrl_n==3] <- abs(rnorm(25, 1.10, 0.45))
    controls$ctrlA[controls$ctrl_n==4] <- abs(rnorm(25, 1.95, 0.50))
    
    id <- sort(rep(seq(1,500,1),4))
    id_n <- rep(seq(0,3,1),500)
    A <- rep(NA,2000)
    samples <- data.frame(id,id_n,A)
    samples$A[samples$id_n==0] <- abs(rnorm(500, 0.85, 0.55))
    samples$A[samples$id_n==1] <- abs(rnorm(500, 0.15, 0.20))
    samples$A[samples$id_n==2] <- abs(rnorm(500, 0.30, 0.35))
    samples$A[samples$id_n==3] <- abs(rnorm(500, 1.05, 0.50))
    samples$CURVE <- sort(rep(seq(1,25,1),80))

    head(controls,8)
    head(samples, 8)
    
> head(controls, 8) # data containing absorptions of controls
      CURVE ctrl_n      ctrlA ctrlC logctrlC
    1     1      1 0.04159145     1 0.000000
    2     1      2 0.52662954    10 2.302585
    3     1      3 1.75846185    40 3.688879
    4     1      4 1.87232576   250 5.521461
    5     2      1 0.06384359     1 0.000000
    6     2      2 0.95464727    10 2.302585
    7     2      3 1.18447674    40 3.688879
    8     2      4 2.43674270   250 5.521461
 
> head(samples, 8) # data containing absorptions of samples
      id id_n         A CURVE
    1  1    0 0.2474628     1
    2  1    1 0.4158992     1
    3  1    2 0.1158692     1
    4  1    3 0.6464121     1
    5  2    0 1.4744212     1
    6  2    1 0.3479539     1
    7  2    2 0.2604562     1
    8  2    3 2.0794687     1
```

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Comment: The question has been edited. I added some code to generate data directly. Is that ok?